# Vuejs unable to receive data using the Event bus

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have two pages/components and an EventBus.

page1/component1 ->

```
EventBus.$emit('customEvent', this.data); 
this.$router.push('urlOfPage2');
```

page2/component ->

```
mounted() {
  EventBus.$on('customEvent', function(val) {
    console.log('value', val);
  }
  console.log('Reached here'); 
}
```

Now, I can see the 'Reached here' part but the $on doesn't work. It just skips it entirely. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: where are you calling `EventBus.$emit('customEvent', this.data);`?

Comment: are you using mixin?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim To send some data from page one to page two

Comment: i which method are you calling that?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim It's a method which gets invoked on pressing a button.

Comment: @Thamerbelfkih There are prebuilt mixins in the template. I didn't code any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your event is emitted on the bus *before* your `page2/component` is created/mounted. I.e. your `page2/component` doesn't exist yet when the event is fired and subscribes to the event only after it has already been emitted. (EventBus doesn't cache and propagate events to later subscribers)

You should instead listen for the event in a higher level component and then pass it to your page2 component as a prop or use a state store (vuex) to pass data/state between your components.

Comment: Ah. This also explains why it was working while I navigated back and forth twice or thrice but never on the first attempt. I will have to learn vuex to implement it. For now, I guess I will store a variable in the EventBus file and use it.

Answer (score 0):

1 - First create a file eventbus.js and add code inside

```
import Vue from 'vue';
const EventBus = new Vue();
export default EventBus;
```

2- page1/component1

```
import EventBus from './event-bus';
```

and use it like this

```
EventBus.$emit('EVENT_NAME', payLoad);
```

Hope its helps

Comment: I have already done that. The problem is at the receiving end. And yes, I have imported the EventBus on both the pages too.

Comment: whats is your problem ?

Comment: The callback function on EventBus.$on doesn't seem to run/trigger

Comment: do you log the result and check if error console.log('err') ?

Comment: Do you add another parameter (payload, err) ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195687/discussion-between-ravy-and-birante).